Google Api Leaderboards возвращает разные userId в записях рекордах (в контексте sdk для unity)
Аналогичная проблема уже поднималась здесь.
Суть проблемы.
✅ Когда берем userId через PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.localUser.id получаем корректный ответ: 107594550310309856665
✅ Когда берем userId через LeaderboardScoreData.PlayerScore.userID получаем корректный ответ: 107594550310309856665
❌ Когда берем userId через LeaderboardScoreData.Scores[0].userID получаем id в каком-то другом формате: a_443231828705151536
Вопрос - почему и как так?
Если кто-то сталкивался с этой проблемой, подскажите пожалуйста причину такого поведения.

В качестве обходного пути я придумал такой костыль, чтобы проверить, что это действительно локальный пользователь:
using var currentPlayerInfo =
  scoreHolder.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getCurrentPlayerInfo");
var friendsListVisibilityStatusRaw =
  currentPlayerInfo.Call<int>("getFriendsListVisibilityStatus");
var friendsListVisibilityStatus =
  AndroidJavaConverter.ToFriendsListVisibilityStatus(friendsListVisibilityStatusRaw);

sLocalUser = friendsListVisibilityStatus > 0;

